# Inequality of double sum with max operator and squared

Tags: statistics, inequality, summation

I am trying to understand a proof, however one inequality remains unclear:

$\mathbb{E} \big( \frac{1}{k_1 k_0} \sum_{i=1}^{k_1} \sum_{j=1}^{k_0} a_{j,i} -b_{j,i} \big)^2 \leq \max_i \frac{1}{k_m^2}\sum_{j=1}^{k_0}\mathbb{E}\big( a_{j,i} -b_{j,i}\big)^2 $,
where $a_{j,i}$ and $b_{j,i}$ are random variables over which the expectation is taken. Is this a consequence of Cauchy Inequality?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $k^2$ should be $k_2^2$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: Do you have any information about the distributions of the $a_{j,i}$ and $b_{j,i}$?

Comment: The authors are not so clear about what k it is one the right side, I assume it is a k equal or larger than $k_1$ and $k_0$. The full description can be found here:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03461.pdf

Comment: One page 39, equation 31. I think the taking of expectations comes at a later step and is not yet needed for this inequality(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very elementary if $k$ could depend on $k_0$ and $k_1$. By Cauchy Schwarz inequality LHS does not exceed $C \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k_1}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k_0}E(a_{ji}-b_{ji})^{2}$ for some $C=C(k_0,k_1)$ and hence LHS $ \leq \max_i Ck_1 \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k_0} E(a_{ji}-b_{ji})^{2}$.

Comment: Is it possible that you mixed up $k_0$ and $k_1$? In the last step, the sum should run until $k_0$ and $k_1$ would be outside as a factor (?). Also, would C's explicit form be: $C = \sum_{i=1}^{k_1} \sum_{j=1}^{k_0} (\frac{1}{k_1k_0})^2 = \frac{1}{k_1k_0}$ ?

Comment: @basho95 Yes, of course. Sorry about that.

Comment: I still wonder though, how the authors come to the $\frac{1}{k_m^2}$ on RHS of the inequality.. If the explicit form of C above holds, then there should be just a $\frac{1}{k_0}$.